# formatting logger in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, logging

I have simple server in ruby with logger included. I'm formatting logger to include part of the string the server receives from the client. it's ruby 2.0.0

```
logger = Logger.new(my_file, 3, 2048000)
logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
logger.info("Starting server.")

server = TCPServer.new 2000

loop do

  Thread.start(server.accept) do | client|

    user_req  = client.recvfrom(2048)[0].chomp

    # req_id is unique
    user_req_id = user_req[0..5]

    logger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
      date_format = datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N")
      "#{severity} [ #{date_format} ] -- [ #{user_req_id} ] ## #{msg}\n"
      end

    logger.info("=1========== #{user_req_id}")
    logger.info("=2========== #{user_req_id}")
    logger.info("=3========== #{user_req_id}")
    client.close

  end
end
```

If I run say 100 requests to this server per second the logger doesn't seem to keep up. What I get in the logfile is:

```
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.024895 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 413895
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:55.983973 ] -- [ 702266 ] ## =3========== 903408
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.026447 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 159765
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.027220 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 623839
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.028004 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 119600
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.030873 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 438547
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.031684 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 350262
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:55.989753 ] -- [ 702266 ] ## =3========== 140647
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.033201 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 711811
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:55.991291 ] -- [ 702266 ] ## =3========== 614276
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.034981 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 016519
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.036542 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 040190
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.037481 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 704540
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.038423 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 099302
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.039301 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =2========== 838688
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.040924 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 411958
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.042387 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 332725
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.045384 ] -- [ 636058 ] ## =3========== 816498
INFO [ 2015-08-12 13:50:56.001173 ] -- [ 237925 ] ## =1========== 237925
```

user_req_id in message is ok, but in formatted logger is not correct. What do I do to fix it?

Comment: I guess, every thread overrides the `formatter` of the former thread. Therefore your message template contains the `user_req_id` of the last started thread and the message contains the `user_req_id` of the thread which calls `logger.info`.

Comment: The whole idea is to have the `user_req_id` in the message template overwritten. Found the answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249243/set-ruby-logger-progname-on-per-thread-basis) Basically set `Thread.current['id'] = user_req_id` and then use `#{Thread.current['id']}` in the formatter.